# Replacement for BuiltInDocumentProperties, When upgrading .Net project's Aspose Cells from 4.7.1.0 to 8.4.0?

Tags: cells, aspose, aspose-cells

I just tried to set a new reference for DLL Aspose cells 8.4.0. And i see so much error, since the properties or objects that is not supported in new version of aspose cells.

```
- Aspose.Cells.Rows
-Aspose.Cells.Columns
-Aspose.Cells.Comments
-Aspose.Cells.BuiltInDocumentProperties
-Aspose.Cells.Validations
-Aspose.Cells.Styles
-Aspose.Cells.Worksheets
```

And i found some replacement of the above in the new 8.4.0. aspose cells;

```
-Aspose.Cells.Row
-Aspose.Cells.Column
-Aspose.Cells.Comment
-________
-Aspose.Cells.Validation
-Aspose.Cells.Style
-Aspose.Cells.Worksheet
```

I have changes these much properties now, But did not find any for **BuiltInDocumentProperties**.
What can be the replacement for this.? Can someone please help on this .?

Answer (score 0):

It is in Aspose.Cells.Properties namespace.

```
Aspose.Cells.Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
// Get reference to property collection
Aspose.Cells.Properties.BuiltInDocumentPropertyCollection properties = workbook.BuiltInDocumentProperties;
// Get individual properties
String author = properties.Author;
String company = properties.Company;
```

I work for Aspose as Developer Evangelist.